# What kind of functions will be put in available list on ftrace in Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, ftrace

I found not every function on the same file is listed in the /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/available_filter_functions for ftrace.
For example, blk_mq_map_swqueue() is listed but blk_mq_add_queue_tag_set() is not even though there are on the file blik-mq.c.
I check out the document[[1](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt)] in the linux kernel. It seems not highlight for it except inline function.
What is the criterion for it?

Comment: blk_mq_add_queue_tag_set() is called only one time in blk_mq_init_allocated_queue(), so it can probably be inlined

Comment: @Roman Zaitsev it makes sense. I will recompile block module with attribute noinline for blk_mq_add_queue_tag_set() and try again.

Comment: @Roman Zaitsev I rebuilt the kernel and noninlined blk_mq_add_queue_tag_set() then I appears on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/available_filter_functions. Excellent!!

Comment: Maybe using trace_printk() is better than noninline a function

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think, that impact of making function non-inline << impact of calling another function like trace_printk()

Answer (score 3):

As Roman Zaitsev comments, I set attribute noninline for blk_mq_add_queue_tag_set(), and then rebuilt the kernel.
It does appear on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/available_filter_functions.
Meanwhile, I can trace it on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace.